# Calculate limits for a function defined by an integral.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, exponential-function

Hello I need help with the second item in the next exercise :

The exercise says:
Let the function $F : \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $F(x) = \int_{x}^{2x}e^{-t^{2}}dt$.

(a) Show that $F(x)$ is a odd function.

(b) Calculate $\lim_{x \to \infty} F(x)$ and $\lim_{x \to -\infty} F(x)$.

For the first item, I showed that $F'$ is an even function, but for the second item I have no ideas. Some suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (b) notice that
$$F(x)=\int_0^{2x}e^{-t^2}dt-\int_0^xe^{-t^2}dt.$$
Taking limits we obtain
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}F(x)=\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}dt-\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}dt=0.$$
The limit $x\to -\infty$ is also equal to $0$ by symmetry.

For the reasoning above to be valid you have to prove before that the improper integral $\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}dt$ is finite (if you haven't already prove it).

**EDIT:** Sorry, I understood you had already solved (a). Just consider
$$F(-x)=\int_{-x}^{-2x}e^{-t^2}dt,$$
and perform the change of variable $t\to -t$.

Comment: Thanks for you help! It's very clear!

Comment: If you don't want to use the fact that the integral $\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-t^2}dt$ converges you could use the estimate $|\int_x^{2x} e^{-t^2} dt| < x e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: @BrunoKrams How did you get this inequality? Also, it is actually $|xe^{-x^2}|$

Comment: @KamalSaleh you are right. It has to be $|xe^{-x^2}|$ to take negative valued of $x$ into account. The estimate is just the length of the interval times the maximum of the integrand